# How can I maintain a connection to a server and get realtime latency updates

Tags: javascript, node.js

I unfortunately do not have any code examples as I'm not sure what to google as this is new to me and just need guidance on what to google, or packages to use

I want to create a simple application with an Electron GUI that shows me the latency to a server, I'm currently playing a game, H1Z1 to be exact that has no in game latency monitor and I thought it would be handy to have this app open on my other monitor that will show me my connection.

I don't know if I'd need to hook the process somehow and get what ips the process is connecting to and then initiate my own connection and monitor the latency.

I could find the IPs through TraceRoute or something but I don't know if a `setInterval` with constant pinging of the server is the best option and was looking for the best suggestions on how to accomplish this or guidance on what I need to google. Sorry for the sub quality question.

To clarify as per comment:

Basically the game client will connect to its back end server, and report its response time in milliseconds, which helps you determine just how laggy your connection is. When you're playing a game without this information it's almost impossible to tell if you missed your shot, bullet didn't register, or if you're just lagging and the server takes to long to update the client which can result in desynchronizing from the server and not getting accurate reports from the server, e.g. I shoot at somebody and the server receives its variables and decides well you shot at X,Y,Z but the character was actually standing at X,Y,Z so you missed but on my end I was aiming perfectly, but I can't tell without knowing just how bad my connection is

So I want to create the most efficient method to determine my connection to the server, I'm just not sure how to go about it

I'm basically expecting to see numbers fluctuation could be anywhere between 40-200ms or something. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: What exactly does "latency to a server" mean?  Can you define what exactly you're trying to measure?  ms to connect?  ms to send a request and receive a response?   Do you just want to know what ping reports?

Comment: @jfriend00 updated my question

Comment: There are multiple contributors to in-game lag.  There's network lag all by itself and then there's the actual lag caused by a busy game server.  The only way to measure the latter is with actual game play.  The pure network lag could be measured with `ping someserver.com` if the receiving host hasn't blocked or disabled ping.

Comment: @jfriend00 my main concern is just the time it takes for my requests to hit the server and come back to my client

Comment: Then `ping` is what you want.  Just exec a ping to the server and collect the results.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok thanks I thought there might be a better way like establishing my own concurrent connection with extremely low data transfer and just monitor its latency on its connection

Comment: If you know how to establish a connection to the actual server and send requests and get responses, then by all means do that.  That requires knowing the auth, login, protocol, message format, etc... being used and you didn't indicate you know that.

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't that's kinda what my main question was, the most efficient way to accomplish this and what packages I would need to google to solve it but that mostly answers that.

Comment: Well, if the connection info isn't documented (which it probably isn't), then it's a reverse engineering process which may be easy or may be hard - it all depends upon how it works.  Reverse engineering is not something simple to describe because it's a hundred different explorations and then learning from that and then deciding where to go from there.  I'd start with a network spy and look at the network traffic the game was sending and see what you learned from that to decide where to go next.